# When will packages uploaded to PPA by dput available?

Tags: ppa

dput completed successfully, but refreshing the corresponding launchpad page doesn't render a change, it still says "no updates" for this PPA, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Recheck your ppa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `dput ppa:warlock/spell` (or whatever)
2. Wait for email from Launchpad, whose subject should say (hopefully):

   ```
   [PPA warlock-spell] [ubuntu/precise] oohitsmagic 1.2.3-4~ppa1precise1 (Accepted)
   ```

   or if you messed something up:

   ```
   [PPA warlock-spell] oohitsmagic_1.2.3-4~ppa1precise1_source.changes rejected
   ```
3. If the upload is successful, *then* you can check the status on the PPA page, where it should say *2 packages waiting to build* (or similar), and you can click on them to see what the approximate wait-time is before the builds for the different architectures begin.
4. Unless you want to keep pressing F5 (hey, I did that for my first PPA upload :), go get a coffee, take a nap, etc., but keep your eye out for the Launchpad email sent *if your build fails*, with a subject like:

   ```
   [Build #1234567] i386 build of oohitsmagic 1.2.4-4~ppa1precise1 in ubuntu precise RELEASE (warlock-spell PPA)
   ```
5. If the build succeeds, that will be show in the status bar for your PPA on the right; note that even after this, you *must wait* for the binaries to be *published* in the PPA before you can go around `apt-get`ting them (a green gear means wait, a check mark means published).

Comment: Yeah, the email come after 2 days..

Answer (score 0):

Wait 1 hour and 30 minutes, then reffresh the PPA page.

Comment: What, have you monopolized all builders until then? :P